# Problem with FixedColumn and RowGroup using datatable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatable, dt

I want to use the `fixedColumns` and `rowGroup` extensions of the `datatable` function. Both work together but when I add the `scrollX` option, I am not satisfied with the display.

Here is an easily reproducible example (the screen size must not be too large to see the `scrollX` action).

Is there a way to fix the `rowGroup` names when I scroll on the x-axis?

```
datatable(mtcars,
          rownames = TRUE,
          extensions = c("FixedColumns",'Scroller',"RowGroup"),
          escape=FALSE,class = 'cell-border stripe',
          selection = "single",
          option=list(fixedHeader = TRUE,
                      deferRender = TRUE,
                      fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 4),
                      scrollX = TRUE,rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 1),
                      scroller = TRUE))
```